# Traduire « to shrug »

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot, anglais

Le verbe anglais *shrug* ne semble pas avoir un équivalent français.  Ainsi, que dit-on quand on veut porter la connotation du mot anglais *shrug*, en français?

En particulier, je voudrais savoir comment on peut traduire le mot comme une interjection, e.g.

> Joe: Do you know where the car keys are?
>   Andrew: *shrug*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

J'ai toujours pensé qu'il s'agissait de « hausser les épaules », mais je ne suis pas sûr de connaître toutes les connotations de « shrug ».  Une différence de formulation est qu'on spécifie toujours « les épaules » en français tandis qu'en anglais elles <strike>me semblent parfois</strike> sont toujours implicites.

Comment: J'aurais dit ça aussi, et d'après la descrition de shrug sur wikipedia, je ne vois pas pourquoi on chercherait autre chose. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrug. Pour le nom/l'action: _haussement d'épaules_ qui me paraît convenir dans l'exemple initial.

Comment: @Joubarc Serait "hausser les épaules" marchera bien comme une interjection?

Comment: *haussement d'épaule* est à peu près la seule expression équivalente... mais pas très concise. Peut-être que le très français "bof" pourrait trouver usage dans certains contextes où *shrug* est utilisé (dans le cas présent, c'est plutôt: "aucune idée" que "bof").

Comment: @Jez: _haussement d'épaule_ (en tant qu'action faite par Andrew), mais à voir en français si cette manie d'entourer des actions d'étoiles est très répandue. Mais sinon, oui.

Comment: @Jez, est-ce que *shrug* est une indication scénique ou bien un mot qu'Andrew dit réellement.  Si c'est un mot, je ne vois pas l'équivalent dans ce contexte, « bof » serait peut-être utilisé dans d'autres.  Ici ce serait peut-être « J'n'sais pas, moi. »

Comment: C'est une indication scénique.

Comment: Ce serait alors « hausse les épaules ». Voir p.e. http://books.google.com/books?ei=DL5UTquOE6XUiAL3vY3iDA&ct=result&id=YR1MAAAAMAAJ&dq=hausse+les+%C3%A9paules&q=%22hausse+les+%C3%A9paules%22#search_anchor (en espérant que ce ne soit pas trop lié à ma session)

Comment: Les épaules sont implicites parce qu'on ne peut *shrugger* que les épaules :)

Comment: @Benjol: avec *shrug*, oui, mais pas en français (on peut hausser d'autres choses, tels que les sourcils)

Comment: J'aimerais bien savoir comment d'autre se traduirait le titre « [Atlas Shrugged](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Grève_(Ayn_Rand)) »

Comment: Quel est le problème avec « haussa les épaules » pour une traduction littérale ?  (Il faut se souvenir qu'Atlas porte le monde sur ses épaules).

Comment: @Joubarc Oui, c'est à n'en pas douter. Internet a réinventé les didascalies... \*sort comme un prince\*